# Hibernate Migration 4.x to 5.0.7.Final: the framework uses hibernate_sequence instead of mySequence (with Oracle and H2)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, sequence-generators

I have updated the hiberate version from 4.0.1.Final to 5.0.7.Final(porting from Jboss 7 to Wildfly 10).

**Problem:**
The hibernate framwork uses hibernate_sequence for the id generation instead of mySequence.

**Hibernate configuration:**
In order to maintain the backward compatibility, hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings is configured as false value.

**Entity configuration:**
The id field is annotated with the following JPA API:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "myGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "myGenerator", sequenceName = "MY_GENERATOR_SEQ")
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;
```

**DB configuration:**
The MY_GENERATOR_SEQ sequence is defined with the "INCREMENT BY 1" option.

The problem occurs for both H2 and Oracle DB.

> **QUESTION**: *I have analyzed the implementation and I don't know if it could be a BUG of Hibernate or any possible bad configuration i did for the backward compatibility???*

---

**Analysis:**
Hibernate during server startup gets some initialization:
SequenceStyleGenerator.configure method defines the QualifiedName sequenceName as "hibernate_sequence", because it tried to get the value from the Properties params.
At this point I noticed that the MY_GENERATOR_SEQ sequenceName was present into the Properties params at runtime with the "sequence" key (sequence=MY_GENERATOR_SEQ) but the retrieve strategy (determineSequenceName) needs the "sequence_name" as key.
So the key used to set the sequence name into the Properties params is from the deprecated class org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.SEQUENCE because of hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false, 
but the SequenceStyleGenerator class needs the org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM key in order to get "MY_GENERATOR_SEQ".

**Potential solutions:**

1. set on SequenceGenerator allocationSize=1 (without setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false)
2. create the sequence MY_GENERATOR_SEQ on the DB with INCREMENT BY 50 (without setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false)

Both the solutions are not applicable into my context.
So the only applicable "solution" is this one:
Extend the Dialect used for Oracle and H2 and override the getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass method in this way:

```
@Override
public Class getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() {
    if ( getIdentityColumnSupport().supportsIdentityColumns() ) {
      return IdentityGenerator.class;
    }
    else {
        //From hibernate-core 5.0.7.Final, org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
        //the original return value was org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.class
      return SequenceGenerator.class;
    }
  }
```

and obviusly set the "databasePlatform" on org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter with the ah-hoc Dialect.

Also submitted to hibernate comunity: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10656

Comment: Did you try with `strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE` instead of `AUTO`

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is strongly related to the impossibility of update the Entity classes in my context, in fact changing the Entity as explained in potential solution 1 or 2 it works.

Comment: the hibernate comunity has confirmed the bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10656

Comment: Thanks for the update +1